# oAuth Client - change response_type

Tags: asp.net-core

How do I change response_type to token in Startup.cs in "OAuth client"?

The server only recognizes the request with the response_type equal to token.

```cs
services.AddOAuth("OurServer", config => {
    config.ClientId = "client_id";
    config.ClientSecret = "client_secret";
    config.CallbackPath = "/oauth/callback";
    config.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://localhost:44382/oauth/authorize";
    config.TokenEndpoint = "https://localhost:44382/oauth/token";
    config.SaveTokens = true;
    config.Events = new OAuthEvents()
    {
        OnCreatingTicket = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.AccessToken;
            var base64payload = accessToken.Split('.')[1];
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64payload);
            var jsonPayload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            var claims = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonPayload);

            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(claim.Key, claim.Value));
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the OAuth authentication handler uses `response_type='code'` internally and does not let you change that- [reference here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/OAuthHandler.cs#L230).

If you wish to change that you have to create a custom OAuth authentication handler and override `BuildChallengeUrl()` where you can set your `response_type`.

You can see how you can use your custom handler here: [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth/OAuthExtensions.cs)

Comment: Hi Plamen Yordanov, I have to create the classes: OAuthExtension.cs and OAuthHander.cs. OAuthExtension will have a method: BuildChallengeUrl to make the change from code to token.  Correct?

Comment: You could do it like that, yes. You can inherit from `OAuthHandler`, override the needed methods and then create an extension method in a separate class to encapsulate the registration. The separate `OAuthExtensions.cs` is not needed, however, you can register your handler directly.

Comment: Thank you very much Plamen. Now i need to intercept url:  /oauth/authorized (CallbackPath). Do you have an example?

Comment: I think its a good idea to post another question with more details.

Comment: Hi, The steps are: 1º Send request to the server (OK working); 2ºUser fills in data manually requested 3ºIf everything is OK 4ºServer redirects to the page with the token in the format (https://<SERVERNAME>/OAuth/Authorized#access_token=85637511-e8e6-4154-8809-f68872e9109a&token_type=bearer&expires_in=86400)   I need to intercept this url and use the token to get the desired data. An example for this step.